# Move or Delete and Force download of Archive after creation

Tags: php, download, directory, archive

To put it simply, I would like my users to be able to download their website files, so I created a "Download Website" button which uses this script to add all files/folders in their directory which is in the variable `$direc` and archive those files/folders.

```
 <?
  ///////// DOWNLOAD ENTIRE WEBSITE:
  if(isset($_POST['download_site'])){
      // define some basics
$rootPath = '../useraccounts/'.$direc.'';
$archiveName = ''.$direc.'.zip';

// initialize the ZIP archive
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($archiveName, ZipArchive::CREATE);

// create recursive directory iterator
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator (new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);

// let's iterate
foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
    $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
    $zip->addFile($filePath);
}

// close the zip file
if (!$zip->close()) {
    echo '<p>There was a problem writing the ZIP archive.</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>Successfully created the ZIP Archive!</p>';
}
  }
  ?>
```

To my surprise, this code works. Although, there are a few hiccups:

1. It doesn't automatically force a download of that archive.
2. It adds the archive in to my main directory rather than moving it to a separate directory of my choice such as `site_downloads` or deletes it up on completed download.

Are these problems at all fixable or if not, is there a better way to do it so my main directory does not get filled with constant downloads? I guess it will cause a problem once a Archive is created more than once, as it uses the Directory name.

Comment: why should it? you don't have anything to actually SEND that .zip file to the user. you're just creating it. you also don't put any path information into `$archiveName`, so you end up with basically just `foo.zip`, and zip willc reate it in the current execution environment's working directory, which is usually the directory that the main script file is located in.

Comment: Yeah I understand I haven't added any code to solve those problems, because I am not sure which code would need to be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using a few different combinations:

```
 <?
  ///////// DOWNLOAD ENTIRE WEBSITE:
  if(isset($_POST['download_site'])){
      // define some basics
$rootPath = '../useraccounts/'.$direc.'';
$archiveName = ''.$direc.'.zip';

// initialize the ZIP archive
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($archiveName, ZipArchive::CREATE);

// create recursive directory iterator
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator (new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);

// let's iterate
foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
    $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
    $zip->addFile($filePath);
}


// close the zip file
if (!$zip->close()) {
    echo '<p>There was a problem writing the ZIP archive.</p>';
} else {
    rename($archiveName, 'user_archives/'.$archiveName.'');
    $yourfile = "user_archives/".$archiveName."";

    $file_name = basename($yourfile);

    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($yourfile));

    readfile($yourfile);
    ignore_user_abort(true);
if (connection_aborted()) {
    unlink('user_archives/'.$archiveName.'');
} else {
    unlink('user_archives/'.$archiveName.'');
}
    echo '<p>Successfully created the ZIP Archive!</p>';
}
  }
  ?>
```

This seems to fix all problems.